# Set element value not show while executing javascript using Android WebView on hotmail

Tags: javascript, android, webview, getelementsbytagname

When I try to execute a block of javascript on Android WebView to set email/password automatically for hotmail, I found the value I set not show at all.

Following is the javascript:

```
String strScripts = "javascript:(function(){" +
  "var items = document.getElementsByTagName('Input');" +
  "for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){" +
     "if( ('text' == items[i].type.toLowerCase() || 'username' == items[i].name.toLowerCase()) ) {items[i].value='accountname';}" +
    "else if( ('email' == items[i].type.toLowerCase()) ) {items[i].value='accountname@hotmail.com';}" +
    "else if( ('password' == items[i].type.toLowerCase() || 'password' == items[i].name.toLowerCase()) ) {items[i].value='123456';}" +
"}}" +
"})()";
mWebView.loadUrl(strScripts);
```

I did this inside onPageFinised callback, so the page should complete the loading.
But after it executed, the values didn't appear on the input fields.

Can anyone offer some help/suggestion on this? Thank you!

Comment: Your code is not JavaScript. There's no type definitions in JS. Remove `String` from the beginning of your code.